# Delete sqlite base based on a column in bash date format

Tags: bash, sqlite, date

I'm trying to delete a part of my database sqlite based on a date.
I want to delete all the lines that are older than 31 days, my column `datefin` are in bash format: `Mon Dec 14 05:00:02 2020`

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
DATESTRING=$(date -d "now -30 day")
echo $DATESTRING
echo "delete from jobmemory where datefin < ' $DATESTRING'; vacuum;" | sqlite3 data.sqlite
```

It seems that my date format isn't recognize by the sql line code.

Comment: The format of your dates is not comparable. Change them to `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you know how I can change the date format in my sqlite database ? i've already tried but the conversion from Mon Dec 14 05:00:02 2020  to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss is quite complicated

Comment: It is complicated because it needs string manipulation. I will post an answer with an UPDATE query.

Comment: Check the UPDATE statement I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the format of your dates to `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` to make it comparable:

```
UPDATE jobmemory
SET datefin = SUBSTR(datefin, -4) || '-' ||
              CASE SUBSTR(datefin, 5, 3)
                WHEN 'Jan' THEN '01'
                WHEN 'Feb' THEN '02'
                WHEN 'Mar' THEN '03'
                WHEN 'Apr' THEN '04'
                WHEN 'May' THEN '05'
                WHEN 'Jun' THEN '06'
                WHEN 'Jul' THEN '07'
                WHEN 'Aug' THEN '08'
                WHEN 'Sep' THEN '09'
                WHEN 'Oct' THEN '10'
                WHEN 'Nov' THEN '11'
                WHEN 'Dec' THEN '12'
              END || '-' ||
              SUBSTR(datefin, 9, 2) || ' ' || 
              SUBSTR(datefin, 12, 8);
```

After you execute the above statement you can compare `datefin` to datetimes of the **same format**.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7f5b83e1ec094d8d7eba0af9bba058cd).

Answer (score 0):

look at this example:

```
DATESTRING=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d "now -30 day")
echo $DATESTRING
```

**output**

```
2020-12-03 14:20:40
```

If you want to have date in a format like this (Mon Dec 14 05:00:02 2020)
just try this code

```
DATESTRING=$(date "+%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y" -d "now -30 day")
echo $DATESTRING
```

**output**

```
Thu Dec 03 14:04:48 2020
```

Test it, I change the date format, it should work for you

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

 It's not working. The format in my database is Mon Dec 14 05:00:02 2020, when I test to "select" or "delete" the database based on your date format, it is the same thing as my exemple.
I think I should change the date format in my sqlite database, do you know how can i do this ?

Comment: I update my answer my friend and it should work now, check it out

Comment: What you propose does not solve the OP's problem. A string like `Thu Dec 03 14:04:48 2020` can't be compared against another string like `Mon Dec 14 05:00:02 2020` because the comparison would be alphabetical. The only comparable text date format is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.